# Can I "autowire" Spring Boot components to MyBatis queries?

Tags: spring-boot, mybatis, spring-mybatis

For an example, here is a sample query:

```
<select id="selectCouponCodes" resultType="SomeDao">
  select *
  from temp_table
  where code = #{code}
</select>
```

Normally, I would pass `code` parameter to the Mybatis mapper. But there are so many queries that use the same `code`, so I'm looking for a shortcut that doesn't use a parameter. Something like this:

```
<select id="selectCouponCodes" resultType="SomeDao">
  select *
  from temp_table
  where code = #{$SomeComponent.code}
</select>
```

`$SomeComponent` is not passed from a parameter. Rather, it is "autowired" to the query. Is there any way to make this possible? If that's not possible, any alternatives would be grateful.

Comment: That's not possible. Parameter passing in MyBatis has nothing to do with Spring dependency injection

Comment: @SimonMartinelli That's a shame. Any alternatives would be grateful if you have any. It seems I should brute-force it until then... Thank you.

Comment: That's the way it work. You want to execute a query so you have to pass the parameters

Comment: Not sure if it's a good idea to autowire parameters to queries. That would assume you are always using the same parameter to them. And... would you autowire by name, by type? If you autowire by type then all threads will step on each other's toes since there would be a single appliction-wide parameter object.